# module_end extended events duration in microseconds?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, extended-events

There is no description for the duration event field for the `module_end` event and I'm struggling to find any additional documentation.

I interpreted this as milliseconds but looking at some of the results this would be incorrect as I have an execution lasting 121 days. Is this duration represented in microseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in microseconds.  See the picture attached here.

[image]

Comment: What edition of SQL Server/SSMS is that from? SSMS 2016 connected to SQL Server 2012 instance there is no description.

Comment: I am connected to SQL 2016 using SSMS 2016. Yes it is not available when you connect a SQL 2012 engine.